# How to do insert action on many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I need your help please,

I do not know where to start, but I'm doing a recruitment management application with the asp.net mvc and wcf technologies, I have a management part of the offers, to start I have a many-to-many relationship between Offers and Candidates table.

Now I want that when the candidate chooses the offer that suits him, when he clicks on the apply button, the offer's id and the id of the candidate is registered in the CandidateOffre association table.

That's what I did, thank you for telling me what I miss so that the insert is done correctly,

- Server side (wcf)

  ```
  public CandidatDTO CreateCandidat(CandidatDTO c)
  {
    CandidatEmploi candidatEmp = new CandidatEmploi();
    CSRMappers.MapCandidatDTOToEntity(c, candidatEmp);

        if (c.OffreEmploi != null && c.OffreEmploi.Any())
        {
            foreach (var f in c.OffreEmploi)
            {
               if (f.IDOffre == 0)
               {
                  OffreEmploi of = new OffreEmploi();
                  CSRMappers.MapOffreDTOToEntity(f, of);
                  candidatEmp.OffreEmploi.Add(of);
               }
               else
               {
                  //look for offer
                  var of = CRE.OffreEmploi.Find(f.IDOffre);
                  if (of != null)
                     candidatEmp.OffreEmploi.Add(of);
               }
            }
        }
        CRE.CandidatEmploi.Add(candidatEmp);
        CRE.SaveChanges();
        c.IDCandidat = candidatEmp.IDCandidat;
        return c;
     }
  ```
- Client side (MVC)

  ```
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult PostE(int id)
     {
       var candidat = new CSRServiceReference.CandidatDTO();
       candidat.OffreEmploi = new List<OffreDTO>();
       if (id > 0)
       {
          var offre = CREClient.GetOffre(id);
          if(offre != null)
          {
               candidat.OffreEmploi.Add(offre);
          }
       }

       candidat.Experiences = new List<CSRServiceReference.ExpProDTO>();
       candidat.Formations = new List<CSRServiceReference.FormationDTO>();
       candidat.ConnInfo = new List<CSRServiceReference.ConnaissInfoDTO>();
       candidat.ConnLing = new List<CSRServiceReference.connaissLingDTO>();
       return View(candidat);
     }


      [HttpPost, ActionName("PostE")]
      public ActionResult PostEmp(CSRServiceReference.CandidatDTO candidat)
     {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           candidat.StatutCandidat = "En attente";

           var newC = CREClient.CreateCandidat(candidat);
           return RedirectToAction("EditCandidat", "Home", new { id = newC.IDCandidat });

        }
        return View(candidat);

     }
  ```

But still the association table is empty unfortunately,

I don't know where is the problem exactly: /

Thank you for answering me.

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you debug your code? To see what is happening? Next to that try to format your code inside the codeblock in your TopicStart because it is unreadable

Comment: Jordy, I hope it is readable now :) Yes I already debug the solution but the association table "OfferCandidat"  is always empty, I do not find the id of the offer nor the id of the candidate.

Comment: Any help please :(

Comment: when you debug, are you able to hit vreakpoints in WCF?

Comment: The problem is in the client part, the id does not pass from the get to the post action, when i put a breakpoint in the post action, exactly in  [ var newC = CREClient.CreateCandidat(candidat);] , the attribute offreEmploi is always null